# What is the mathematics behind the turtlebot calibration?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because of problems with the calibration, I try to understand what is happening in the turtlebot_calibration node, specifically the scan_to_angle.py, method scan_cb(). This is a piece of code that attempts to calculate a single angle from a scan. The code is:

```
   for r in msg.ranges:
        if angle > self.min_angle and angle < self.max_angle and r < msg.range_max:
            x = sin(angle) * r
            y = cos(angle) * r
            sum_x += x
            sum_y += y
            sum_xx += x*x
            sum_xy += x*y
            num += 1
        angle += d_angle
    if num > 0:
        angle=atan2((-sum_x*sum_y+num*sum_xy)/(num*sum_xx-sum_x*sum_x), 1)
        res = ScanAngle()
        res.header = msg.header
        res.scan_angle = angle
        self.pub.publish(res)
    else:
        rospy.logerr("Please point me at a wall.")
```

Can someone tell me more about the mathematics behind this?

You may also notice that the algorithm uses the atan2() in a unintended way, causing a divide by zero in case of all x = 0 (unlikely) or num = 1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44603/what-is-the-mathematics-behind-the-turtlebot-calibration?/) by [Jaap Reitsma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3260/jaap-reitsma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question: I remembered again this type of code: It is [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression). The basics is that the wall is assumed to be straight and that the laser scanner or Kinect projects within a sufficient small window a number of scans with points (range, angle) on a straight line y = a.x + b. These polar coordinates are converted to (x, y) coordinates and inserted in a linear regression (least squares) formula. We are interested in the direction of the line, or better the perpendicular line (that is rotated 90 degrees). I think the code snip above is mixing the cos and sin as for a right-handed coordinate system the normal definition is x = r.cos(alfa). Because of the perpendicular line the final result is ok after all.

For a line you need of course at least 2 scan points, and for a reliable result many more. Perhaps you also need to average the angle for less noise.

---

Originally posted by [Jaap Reitsma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3260/jaap-reitsma/) with karma: 76 on 2012-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4